# Workplace relationships

Tags: relationships, work-life-balance

My fiancé and I have worked together directly in the company we are with for a while now, and we disclosed our relationship to them in the very beginning. Can they after a year of knowing we were together, and promoting me to a higher position with a raise come back and reprimand us for violating company policy now when they knew about it the entire time?

Comment: After promotion did you become your fiance's boss?

Comment: You asked whether "*they* can do something".  It's impossible to answer. People tend to do different sort of things and at times behave quite irrationally.

Comment: This seems like a company specific issue. Go find any HR guidelines your company has on workplace relationships and make sure you followed all protocols. If so, and if you have record of alerting them to the situation, I see no reason why they *should* reprimand you now. That said, they *can* reprimand you however they feel like it, and how you feel about that and react to it is up to you.

Comment: What does "reprimand" mean and where in the world are you? Generally speaking, "they" can do as "they" please, only laws will restrict that... and laws are not global, you will need to tell us where in the world you work.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you may want to do is to read the employee handbook or talk to HR to see if your relationship violates the company policy.

Some companies specifically do not allow a manager to have a romantic relationship with a person who reports to him/her.

Comment: In which case the solution is simple: Move one of the people to another management chain so there's no conflict of interest. That's certainly how I've seen it handled in my (mumble)-decade career...